# VBA countifs within named range with using array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, countif

Hello all good people,

please any help appreciated. I am trying to build macro to show custom histogram and I am stuck on this:

```
'declaration of range "VYBER" contains various numbers ususaly in range +-0,5
Set WS = Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
Set BUNKA = WS.Range(WS.Cells(RADEK, 8), WS.Cells(RADEK, 8))
Set VYBER = WS.Range(BUNKA, BUNKA.End(xlToRight))
USL = WS.Range(WS.Cells(RADEK, 2), WS.Cells(RADEK, 2)).Value
LSL = WS.Range(WS.Cells(RADEK, 3), WS.Cells(RADEK, 3)).Value

'BINs declaration as array, USL and LSL are upper and lower limits taken from cells

Dim BIN() As Variant
ReDim BIN(1 To 23)

BINWIDTH = (USL - LSL) / 10
BIN(1) = -100
BIN(2) = 2 * LSL
BIN(23) = 100

For i = 3 To 22

BIN(i) = Round(BIN(i - 1) + BINWIDTH, 1)

Next i

'Frequency/YAXIS

Dim YAXIS() As Variant
ReDim YAXIS(1 To 22)

For i = 1 To 22

YAXIS(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(VYBER, ">=" & BIN(i), VYBER, "<" & BIN(i + 1))

Next i
```

What is not working properly is line:

```
YAXIS(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(VYBER, ">=" & BIN(i), VYBER, "<" & BIN(i + 1))
```

There is no error but it just gives me all 0. Even I know the data are in there right. When I print BINs and VYBER in msg box I can see there are right data, but the countifs does not processes them.

Can the reason be in that number are stored from cell to array with coma instead of dot?

Please help. Thank you very much.

---------EDIT---------

```
Debug.Print VYBER.Address, BIN(i), BIN(i + 1), YAXIS(i)
```

Gives me:

```
$H$9:$AU$9    -100          -1             0 
$H$9:$AU$9    -1            -0,9           0 
$H$9:$AU$9    -0,9          -0,8           0 
$H$9:$AU$9    -0,8          -0,7           0 
$H$9:$AU$9    -0,7          -0,6           0 
$H$9:$AU$9    -0,6          -0,5           0 
$H$9:$AU$9    -0,5          -0,4           0 
$H$9:$AU$9    -0,4          -0,3           0 
$H$9:$AU$9    -0,3          -0,2           0 
$H$9:$AU$9    -0,2          -0,1           0 
$H$9:$AU$9    -0,1           0             0 
$H$9:$AU$9     0             0,1           0 
$H$9:$AU$9     0,1           0,2           0 
$H$9:$AU$9     0,2           0,3           0 
$H$9:$AU$9     0,3           0,4           0 
$H$9:$AU$9     0,4           0,5           0 
$H$9:$AU$9     0,5           0,6           0 
$H$9:$AU$9     0,6           0,7           0 
$H$9:$AU$9     0,7           0,8           0 
$H$9:$AU$9     0,8           0,9           0 
$H$9:$AU$9     0,9           1             0 
$H$9:$AU$9     1             100           0
```

And `Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(VYBER.Value)), " ")` is:

```
0,138 0,324 0,156 0,132 0,13 0,263 0,185 0,27 0,147 0,16 0,187 0,284 0,204 0,239 0,172 0,157 0,269 0,228 0,283 0,22 0,151 0,322 0,287 0,317 0,32 0,242 0,27 0,225 0,202 0,207 0,242 0,222 0,322 0,277 0,225 0,297 0,296 0,168 0,207 0,247
```

Comment: if you pause the code part-way, `Debug.print` VYBER.Address, BIN(i) and BIN(i + 1) and then manually write them into a COUNTIFS() function in your worksheet, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, I run the function separately in excel as formula and it is working just fine with exact values which are inside the BIN and VYBER.

Comment: Example from debug.print (range,BIN(i),BIN(i+1),result as YAXIS) `$H$6:$AU$6    0          0,1           0 ` which is incorect same numbers in formulas in cells gives result 14. There must be something wrong with the COUNTIFs function.

Comment: OK, try if you `Dim BIN() As Long` instead of Variant?

Comment: Then it is not working at all. If Ill do long from some reason all values in bin lower than 1 will be rounded to 1. The bin as it is correct looks like: `-100 -1 -0,9 -0,8 -0,7 -0,6 -0,5 -0,4 -0,3 -0,2 -0,1 0 0,1 0,2 0,3 0,4 0,5 0,6 0,7 0,8 0,9 1 100`

Comment: Sorry I forgot the decimals ... try `As Double`

Comment: `as double` gives same results `as Variant` but for some reason with `as double` stops working `MsgBox Join(BIN, " ")` IDK why :D

Comment: What  decimal separator is displayed in the cells? dot or comma

Comment: As I wrote, excel is in comas. In cells are comas. But I think I figured out that it is not allowed to use array for countifs function because there needs to be used only range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not solve it as I indended. Imho it is not possible, so I bypassed the issue with my own countif (primitive):

```
Dim YAXIS()
ReDim YAXIS(1 To 22)
pocitadlo = 0

For i = 1 To 22
For Each cel In VYBER
If cel.Value >= BIN(i) And cel.Value < BIN(i + 1) Then
pocitadlo = pocitadlo + 1
Else
End If
Next cel


YAXIS(i) = pocitadlo
pocitadlo = 0
'Debug.Print pocitadlo, BIN(i), n, YAXIS(i)
Next i
```

Which works fine for me.